# libxml2-dev not installing on raspbian/debian

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, libxml2

When I `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` I receive the error
`libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.4+dfsg1-1+b1) but 2.9.4+dfsg1-1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

I tried to follow this guide: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=105859

but when I get to `cd ~/libxml2-2.9.1` the directory does not exist. Here is my actual output:

```
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglew1.10 liborcus-0.8-0 libpython3.4 libpython3.4-dev libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib
  libwps-0.3-3 python3.4 python3.4-dev python3.4-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib
  python python-minimal python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python-tk python2.7-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython-dev libpython2.7-dev python-dev python2.7-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython-stdlib libpython2.7 libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python python-minimal python2.7
  python2.7-minimal
8 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 784 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 37.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python2.7 armhf 2.7.12-2 [277 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpython2.7 armhf 2.7.12-2 [913 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpython2.7-stdlib armhf 2.7.12-2 [1,843 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python2.7-minimal armhf 2.7.12-2 [1,173 kB]  
Get:5 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpython2.7-minimal armhf 2.7.12-2 [388 kB] 
Get:6 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-minimal armhf 2.7.11-2 [40.3 kB]      
Get:7 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python armhf 2.7.11-2 [153 kB]               
Get:8 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpython-stdlib armhf 2.7.11-2 [19.8 kB]    
Get:9 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpython2.7-dev armhf 2.7.12-2 [27.5 MB]    
Get:10 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libpython-dev armhf 2.7.11-2 [19.8 kB]      
Get:11 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python2.7-dev armhf 2.7.12-2 [278 kB]       
Get:12 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-dev armhf 2.7.11-2 [1,132 B]         
Fetched 32.6 MB in 25s (1,284 kB/s)                                                                        
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 130446 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7 (2.7.12-2) over (2.7.9-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7:armhf (2.7.12-2) over (2.7.9-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-stdlib_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-stdlib:armhf (2.7.12-2) over (2.7.9-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-minimal_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-minimal (2.7.12-2) over (2.7.9-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-minimal_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-minimal:armhf (2.7.12-2) over (2.7.9-2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python-minimal_2.7.11-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python-minimal (2.7.11-2) over (2.7.9-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-4) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-minimal:armhf (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.11-2) ...
(Reading database ... 130445 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python_2.7.11-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python (2.7.11-2) over (2.7.9-1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython-stdlib_2.7.11-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-stdlib:armhf (2.7.11-2) over (2.7.9-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7-dev:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython2.7-dev_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7-dev:armhf (2.7.12-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython-dev:armhf.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython-dev_2.7.11-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libpython-dev:armhf (2.7.11-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python2.7-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../python2.7-dev_2.7.12-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python2.7-dev (2.7.12-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../python-dev_2.7.11-2_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python-dev (2.7.11-2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-5) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:armhf (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up libpython-stdlib:armhf (2.7.11-2) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:armhf (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-dev:armhf (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up python2.7-dev (2.7.12-2) ...
Setting up python (2.7.11-2) ...
Setting up libpython-dev:armhf (2.7.11-2) ...
Setting up python-dev (2.7.11-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-4) ...
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo apt-get install python-lxml
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libglew1.10 liborcus-0.8-0 libpython3.4 libpython3.4-dev libpython3.4-minimal libpython3.4-stdlib
  libwps-0.3-3 python3.4 python3.4-dev python3.4-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-bs4
Suggested packages:
  python-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-bs4 python-lxml
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 784 not upgraded.
Need to get 761 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,991 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-bs4 all 4.5.0-1 [85.5 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf python-lxml armhf 3.6.0-1 [675 kB]
Fetched 761 kB in 2s (301 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package python-bs4.
(Reading database ... 130580 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-bs4_4.5.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-bs4 (4.5.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-lxml.
Preparing to unpack .../python-lxml_3.6.0-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking python-lxml (3.6.0-1) ...
Setting up python-bs4 (4.5.0-1) ...
Setting up python-lxml (3.6.0-1) ...
pi@rpi:~ $ sudo dpkg -l |grep libxml2
ii  libxml2:armhf                         2.9.1+dfsg1-5+deb8u2                      armhf        GNOME XML library
ii  python-lxml                           3.6.0-1                                   armhf        pythonic binding for the libxml2 and libxslt libraries
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up downloading from source: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libxml2

And then installing manually via `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`

Answer (score 0):

"784 not upgraded."

Are you updated whenever your raspian? Maybe you can't install this because you haven't stable packages.