# How to install pandasdmx on raspbian raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, libxml2

I tried to install a pandasdmx package on Raspbian (Linux for Raspberry Pi).
It failed because in is not possible to install libxml2 on the Raspbian.
Here is the error message that I get:

```
*********************************************************************************  
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2   installed?  
********************************************************************************* 

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Before this, I installed the libxl2 manually using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38938055/libxml2-dev-not-installing-on-raspbian-debian), and the installation did seem to work.

Any hint?

Comment: Did the installation fail or did it throw the same error after the installation succeeded? can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was in the libxml installation.
The proper way to do it on raspbian:
[Why can't I get `pip install lxml` to work within a virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019942/why-cant-i-get-pip-install-lxml-to-work-within-a-virtualenv)